# How to select the total of publications that users have made with laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

my problem is that I want the number of published promotions that registered users have made in a graphic with Highcharts using the library of Laravel Charts, the question is that I can get you to print the names of the users. but I could not get him to print the total number of his publications

My code:

```
$users = User::select('nombre_empresa')->WhereIn('role_id',[2,3])->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {

            $empresas[] = $user->nombre_empresa;
            $id[] = $user->id;
            $publicaciones[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$id)->get()->count();

    }

    $chart = new TotalPromociones;
    $chart->title('Total de promociones publicadas por socios');
    $chart->labels($empresas);
    $chart->dataset('Numero de promociones','bar', ([$publicaciones]));
    $chart->dataset('Total de promociones publicadas = '.$total_promociones,'bar',[]);
```

[the graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGbp3.png)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships see the section for withCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes in code as per below:

```
    $users = User::WhereIn('role_id',[2,3])->pluck('nombre_empresa', 'id');

    $empresas = [];
    $publicaciones = [];

    foreach ($users as $key => $val) {

            $empresas[] = $val;
            $publicaciones[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$key)->count();

    }

    $chart = new TotalPromociones;
    $chart->title('Total de promociones publicadas por socios');
    $chart->labels($empresas);
    $chart->dataset('Numero de promociones','bar', ([$publicaciones]));
    $chart->dataset('Total de promociones publicadas = '.$total_promociones,'bar',[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a method to count the number of results from a relationship.

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will
>   place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models. For example:

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

In your case this will be something like:

```
$users = User::select('nombre_empresa')->withCount('promociones')->WhereIn('role_id',[2,3])->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $empresas[] = $user->nombre_empresa;
    $id[] = $user->id;
    $publicaciones[] = $user->promociones_count;
}
```

The value passed to the `withCount()` method should be the same as the method name for the relationship with `Promociones` given in your `User` model.

Comment: Probably the foreach is no longer necessary. I think you could replace `$empresas` with `$users->pluck('nombre_empresa')`, and the same with the others.

Comment: You would still need to loop through for the user id and the user promotion count. You're right though, you could get rid of the foreach all together if the OP was willing to change the resulting data format slightly.